# Why do I keep getting this error when I try to connect mongodb to my next.js project

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I keep getting this error when I try to connect my mongodb to my user api route file. I don't know what is going wrong and I do not know how to solve it, but I'm sure this is what my teacher wrote on his computer and it worked without any errors.

[image]

This is what my dbconnection file looks like

```
//   MongoDB Connection

import mongoose from "mongoose";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
    throw new Error("Please define the MONGODB_URL environment variable inside .env.local");
}

let cached = global.mongoose;

if (!cached) {
    cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function dbConnect() {
    if (cached.conn) {
        return cached.conn;
    }

    if (!cached.promise) {
        const opts = {
            bufferCommands: false,
        };

        cached.promise = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, opts).then((mongoose) => {
            return mongoose;
        });
    }
    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
    return cached.conn;
}

export default dbConnect;
```

And this is how I define my user routes to the /api/user endpoint

```
import Users from "../../../api/models/Users";
import dbConnect from "../../util/mongo";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const { method } = req;
    dbConnect()

    switch (method) {
        case "GET":
            try {
                const res = await Users.find();
                res.status(200).json(res);
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(500).json(error);
            }

            break;
        case "POST":
            console.log(POST);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            console.log(PUT);
            break;
        case "Delete":
            console.log(Delete);
            break;
    }
}
```

my package.json file is thus:

```
  "name": "smooon",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.7.3",
    "mongodb-client-encryption": "^2.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.5",
    "next": "12.3.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-snowfall": "^1.2.1",
    "react-spinners-kit": "^1.9.1",
    "react-tinder-card": "^1.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.3.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: delete your `node_modules` folder and run npm install once more, and see if error still persist

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I just did, but I'm getting the error still.

Comment: can u share your package.json?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Please check,  I've added it.

Comment: can u remove and install mongodb to latest version? it's at 4.10.0 now. Is there any reason why you need it installed independently? Typically we just install mongoose and the correct version will be included as a dependency

Comment: I'm just trying out a lot of things to see what works out. Independently, I still get the errors. I've removed monogo and mongo client, but nothing has changed.  

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248789/discussion-between-crayonne-and-someone-special).